# How to uncompress php's gzcompress in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, zlib

I am making an android app and a website that downloads info from a php script. The php script compresses the data using `gzcompress($dat, 9);`.

I know how to uncompressed it in android, but how do you do it in javascript?

In this post:
[Compress data in php and uncompress in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561828/compress-data-in-php-and-uncompress-in-javascript)

sstringer mentions you can put a special header when using php's `gzencode` so jquery can automatically uncompress it. Is there a way for the way I am doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this myself once. I decided to go to the ajax route and then redirect.

If you know where the file is being stored on the server you could post that to a php script which decompresses it and saves the file somewhere. Next, return this in the ajax response and then just redirect the user to the saved, decompressed file.

There is a project on GitHub: https://github.com/gcanu/gzip.js

That might be what you are looking for.